# Clicking on Google ad in a WebView loads the link in the WebView itself

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm loading a Google ad in a `WebView` with the code shown below. When I click on the ad the link opens in the `WebView` itself.

How can I open it in Android browser?

I tried setting a `WebViewClient` with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` but when I click the ad the method is not called.

When I run the javascript code in `Chrome` on my pc it opens correctly in a new window.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I tried to use `onLoadResource` to detect click events by listening to loading of an url containing `googleads.g.doubleclick.net` but the issue is that such url is loaded during the ad loading, i.e. before clicking.

How can I mimic the behaviour of Chrome, which opens the url in a new window without any hacking?

**ad.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
        var gads = document.createElement('script');
        gads.async = true;
        gads.type = 'text/javascript';
        var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
        gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
        var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('/123456789/xxxx', [320, 50], 'div-gpt-ad-123456789-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='div-gpt-ad-123456789-0' style='width:320px; height:50px;'>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-123456789-0'); });
        </script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**java code**

```
WebView ad = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad);
ad.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ad.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {

        // never gets here!
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);               
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

        if (url.contains("googleads.g.doubleclick.net")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            view.stopLoading();
        }
    }
});
ad.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/ad.html");
```

Comment: Why don't you put your if(url.contains("googleads.g.... condition in shouldOverrideURlLoading and return `true`. Put this before its super function.

Comment: Because as specified in my question, the method shouldOverrideURlLoading is never called.

Comment: I can't run yoru code, as I don't have any such URL to load, but what I can concur is, your `onLoadResource()` loads first, and stops that URL from loading. Hence, it does not reach `shouldOverride`. So, remove `onLoadResource()` and put its code in shouldOverride`.